Why does corrin not exist on its own?
I was reading about the vitamins and came across Corrin on a tangent. The wikipedia article suggests that corrin " [is] not known to exist on its own." However, looking at the molecule, it seems perfectly reasonable that this is a stable structure. Yes, the structure is not aromatic like the corrole structure, but the rings are 5-membered heterocycles, which look perfectly stable, and the linkages between them also do not seem too destabilising.
So I ask: what is the reason behind this inability of corrin to exist on its own? Is it ring strain? One notices that the molecule is not symmetric as well. The upper right and lower two rings are linked by a R-CH=R bridge, while the lower left and the upper left rings are linked directly to each other. Perhaps this is a reason why it could be unstable, however this seems dubious. After all, vitamin B12 exists and features the same structure! The only difference is the functionalisation of the corrin ring with many carboxylic acid and amide groups. There must be something about the corrin ring in B12 versus the unfunctionalised ring that makes it more stable. Or perhaps it is the binding of cobalt (and possible backbonding?) that allows stability in B12. I cannot come up with a convincing reason, however. Any help is much appreciated!

It can be made, but does not occur in organisms. It can be gathered from the context of the article :/

Indeed this is a question of "not isolated [from living organisms.]" Corrins and derivatives have been extensively studied in the 60s and 70s as part of the Vitamin $B_{12}$ total synthesis. A google search should net you many freely available papers on the topic. Or, look at the total synthesis of B12 here.

I think it remains a valid question, although perhaps the OP would care to clarify what it is that they think unstable? Do they mean the apo (metal-free) ring system? A quick look at the Wikipedia shows final structures all involving a metal center, no apo structures.

Thank you, @BuckThorn. It seems my concerns have been misunderstood! I have searched on google for these structures before asking this question, and found very small information on specifically metal-free corrin ligands. And I have looked at the B12 synthesis—most of it is with respect to cobyric acid, on Wikipedia or not Wikipedia. I ask about corrin.

@JamesA I found this paper describing their chemistry and synthesis. While it does not describe the “pure” corrin synthesis, it does describe the synthesis and isolation of metal-free corrin ligands.
